# simple exception in javascript cause the codeto not work

Tags: javascript, html, exception

I write simple Javascript division function and doing exception handling 
using `throw` , `try()` and `catch()` the problem is that the code with exception
not work at all even prompt not shown

here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript lab</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script language="javascript">

            function div(a,b) { 
              if (b == 0)
                throw { name: 'notallowed', message: 'div by zero' };
                var c = a/b;
                alert(c);
              }
            }

            try {
              var x = prompt("Enter num1"); 
              var y = prompt("Enter num2"); 

              div(a,b);
            }
            catch(e) {
              alert("Error: "+e.message);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: you're missing an { somewhere - or there's an extra } after the alert(c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//modify 
function div(a,b) { //function div(a,b)
  if (b == 0){
    throw { name: 'notallowed', message: 'div by zero' };
     var c = a/b;
    alert(c);
  }
}


try {
  var x = prompt("Enter num1"); 
  var y = prompt("Enter num2"); 

  //modify
  div(x,y);//div(a,b);
}
catch(e) {
  alert("Error: "+e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this could be works fine

```
function div(a,b) { 
   if (b == 0){
       throw { name: 'notallowed', message: 'div by zero' };
   }
   var c = a/b;
   alert(c);
}
```

You have missed a `{` at the end of `if(b==0)`

Comment: check where the closing } on the if is!

Comment: @BigMike this was a one and the second error instead of x,y as parameters in function call i pass a,b

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
        function div(a,b) { 
          if (b == 0) {
            throw { name: 'notallowed', message: 'div by zero' };
          }
          var c = a/b;
          alert(c);
        }


        try {
          var x = prompt("Enter num1"); 
          var y = prompt("Enter num2"); 

          div(x,y);
        }
        catch(e) {
          alert("Error: "+e.message);
        }
```